# Variables not being sent and executed properly in tkinter and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

im using tkinter and sqlite3 to create a inventory management system for a an aquarium as a project for college. As im creating my report function ive encountered a bizzare bug that ive tried to fix alot.

I am attempting to use a user input as a SQL query so the user can pull whatever data they are looking for into a tkinter table. The bug im getting is that my code will not send over the entered query to the table subroutine and as a result of this the table window opens blank and does not recieve the command ive given it.

I have verified that this is the cause of it because ive tried printing out the command (Entered) in the table subroutine and it is blank.

I would give an error message but there is none

here is my code snippet:

```
def displaytable(Entered):
  repwin1 = Tk()
  repwin1.geometry("400x400")
  print(Entered)
  r_set=con.execute(Entered);
  i=0 
  for Fishy in r_set: 
      for j in range(len(Fishy)):
          e = Entry(repwin1, width=5, fg='blue') 
          e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
          e.insert(END, Fishy[j])
      i=i+1
  print("c")
  


def ReportGUI():
 repwin = Tk()
 repwin.geometry("400x400")

 label12 = Label(repwin, text="assisted query builder")
 label12.pack()

 entryrep = Entry(repwin,width=50)
 entryrep.focus_set()
 entryrep.pack()

 Entered = entryrep.get()

 buttonfish = ttk.Button(repwin, text= "Report",width= 20, command= lambda : displaytable(Entered))
 
 buttonfish.pack()
```

Comment: You should call `entryrep.get()` inside `displaytable()` or the lambda. Also use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for child windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Entered = entryrep.get()` is executed just after the entry box is created, so `Entered` is always empty string.

You need to call `entryrep.get()` inside the lambda instead:

```py
buttonfish = ttk.Button(repwin, text="Report", width=20,
                        command=lambda: displaytable(entryrep.get()))
```